# Using a JavaScript variable in a Rails call made inside a JavaScript function: how do Ajax helps here?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I rely on a variable defined by a JavaScript object to update (re-render) a Ruby on Rails partial inside a view, but it is not working. From all I read it tells me the only possible way for this to work is to use an Ajax call, however I'm new to this and couldn't quite grasp why (given the JavaScript variable is available before the Rails command is defined), nor exactly how I should do it.

My Rails view has this HTML bit I'm looking to

```
<div id="myevent">
    <% if @pocket.events.any? %>
        <%= @event = @pocket.events.first %>
        <%= render @event %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

On that same view I implement a JavaScript object made up of various clickable nodes, each node denoting an event with a unique id. I want to re-render the `#myevent` section above each time someone clicks on a different node.

As someone new to front-end programming, I've tried this:

```
timeline.on('click', function (properties) {
    logEvent('click', properties);
    var item = properties["item"];
    $('#myevent').html("<%= escape_javascript render (@pocket.events.find_by id:" + item + ") %>");
```

The JavaScript variable 'item' contains the event id from the clicked node. As you may know, the last line above doesn't work, Rails raises an ArgumentError with the message:

> 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

It does works if I set a hardcoded id, so the rationale seems to be right:

```
$('#myevent').html("<%= escape_javascript render (@pocket.events.find_by id: 5) %>");
```

I have tried using the partial format as well:

```
$('#event').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial=>'shared/event', :locals=> {event_id: " + item + "} %>")
```

And then using the following method to recover the right event in the `'shared/event' partial`:

```
<%= @event = Event.find(event_id) %>
```

however, it fails with a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error because it doesn't really replace the `string "+ item +"` by the value of that JavaScript variable:

```
Couldn't find Event with 'id'=+item+
```

The "pain" is that, no matter how I try I can't find a way to use the JavaScript defined variable on that Rails calls. It looks like the solution would be to use an Ajax call but I reckon after many tries I don't get to work this out by myself. I would really appreciate a hand here.

Comment: It doesn't work because everything enclosed bewteen `<% ` and `%>` is procesed **before** page rendering, so you need to set up item in the server, not on the client. That's why setting it manually works, but dynamically doesn't. As you mentioned, ajax is needed for that; you can read about rails and ajax [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#an-introduction-to-ajax).

Comment: Thank you for confirming ajax is indeed the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what happens is that the .erb portion of the code is only parsed at render time, so when the page first renders, there's really no `item` to append to that. In turn, when you hardcode it, it's able to parse that ruby code and render correctly.

So indeed you need to contact the server.

What I would do would be:

```
timeline.on('click', function (properties) {
    var item = properties["item"];
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/route_to_your_controller',
      data: { event_id: item },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data['success']) {
          $('#myevent').html(data['html']);
        }
        else {
          alert('oopsss take care of this');
        }
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
});
```

**routes.rb**

```
post '/route_to_your_controller', to: 'controller#spew_html'
```

then, saying you have a route to this action on a controller:

```
def spew_html
  # you should take care of failed finds, errors that might occur, have a before_action to check legality of ajax call, and even possibly accept only xhr, return false unless request.xhr? etc
  event_id = params[:event_id]
  html_partial = render_to_string 'shared/event', locals: { event_id: event_id }
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { html: html_partial, success: true } }
  end
end
```

As a bonus, one pattern I like to implement when possible is just having the same route for GET be the POST for whatever ajax, so that then I can simply do:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: window.location.pathname,
  //...
});
```

And let the controller know how to deal with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful reply, Micael! Your solution is to the point and solved the problem for me, much appreciated! I would have it 'marked as solved' but there just doesn't seem to be an option for this here.

Comment: @laudares there is on the left side, glad it helped

Comment: I've looked all around for that solved button but it doesn't show to me - instead when I try to up-vote your answer I get a "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicity displayed post score"
@paul-roub - is there anything else I could do to "close" my request for help here ?